# BrowserStack e2e tests with mock server

Tags: selenium, express, nightwatch.js, browserstack, mockserver

My goal is to set up an environment where CircleCI would run my e2e tests on BrowserStack in different browsers.

My tests are assuming that there is a mock server running. (E.g. tests are checking whether a certain call to the mock server has been made or not.)

I learned that there is such a thing as `local` testing for BrowserStack, but whenever I'd like to start the mock server on port `65432` it says the port is already being used. `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::65432`

I have an Express mock server running (on port `65432`), tests are ran by Nightwatch against Selenium server.

So far I only saw examples which run tests against homepages which are living on the internet (like `google.com`), but I would like to run my own mock server locally and run my tests against it.

Is there a way where I could run a mock server and run my tests with Nightwatch and Selenium against that mock server and all done by a CI tool running the tests on BrowserStack?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a internal website (*not accessible to public*) hosted on your machine (*using mock server - [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html), [Express Mock Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mock-server), etc*) and wish to run the Selenium based scripts to test that application on BrowserStack, then you can use the [Local Testing feature](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing-internals).

You simply need to `run the binary file` that they provide on your local machine (*where the internal website is accessible*) and set the capability '`browserstack.local`' to '`true`'. Hence the tests running on BrowserStack will be able to access your internal website. I would recommend you to review the documentation [here](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing). You can checkout the documentation on NightwatchJS-BrowserStack [here](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/nightwatch#running-local-test).

If you wish to trigger the tests using CircleCI. They provide the plug-in for CircleCI as well, read more on the same [here](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/continuous-integration#ci-plugins). The plug-in itself will handle the Local Testing for you in that case.

Comment: thx @ckzgraphics for your answer, the [Local Testing Internals](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing-internals) link helped me a lot to get a better understanding, however my problem was a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers: my problem was parallelism - I set 2 workers (child processes basically) with the following object:

```
"test_workers": {
    'enabled': true,
    'workers': 2
}
```

I found this setup from one of the examples which I can't find anymore, but if you are running your Nightwatch tests with your own mock server this might mess up the test suite since every worker will try to spin up a mock server for it's own tests, which will obviously fail.